# sendKeys with p:calendar does not yield reliable results from one run to another

Tags: selenium-webdriver, primefaces

I am using selenium to fill a p:calendar field. Instead of using the date picker, **I send the keys to the field directly.**

```
webDriver.findElement(By.id("theId").sendKeys("06031984");
```

Before and after this, I am interacting with various other elements on the page. With each run, **I am getting different values** appearing in my date input field - and rarely are these the correct ones:

- 40.60.3198
- 98.40.6031
- 06.03.1984 <- Correct

The order of the keys seems to be shifted, probably by the ajax calls in the p:calendar:

```
<p:calendar id="theId" styleClass="date-input"
            binding="#{date}" navigator="true"
            value="#{aView.date}"
            validator="dateValidator"
            yearRange="#{validatorService.dateRange}"
            pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" mask="99.99.9999" readonlyInput="false"
            readonly="false" required="true" showOn="button"
            requiredMessage="#{i18n['aMsg']}"
            locale="de">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
            update="many elements"
            oncomplete="updateTabbing();" />
    <p:ajax event="change"
            update="many elements"
            oncomplete="updateTabbing();" />
</p:calendar>
```

**Is there a way to ensure the correct value ends up in the field ?**
So far I find working with Selenium (and a JSF page) to be a bit of a hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try adding some wait and send tab key

or injecting java script for the value would Solve this problem

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByid('theId').value = '06.03.1984';");

Please let me know if its solving the problem.

Comment: I already tried waits and tabs but it did not work. The Javascript idea is good, however I am getting this error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: document.getElementsByid is not a function

Comment: I changed the JavaScript to this and now it works: js.executeScript("document.getElementById('theId').value = '06.03.1984';"); Just edit your response and I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I started contributing today on StackoverFlow.
happy that i could find some solution 
cheers 
-Dharam